# Google search results hijacked locally / displaying moot in all browsers

Tags: windows, man-in-the-middle, google

So, since yesterday I have quite obviously caught something that Windows Defender doesn't recognize.

***Symptoms:***

- All Google services suffer from Ad injection (non-YouTube ad overlays that cannot be removed as they are not clickable or visible)
- Most notably: Google search results have been hijacked! Here is a video showing how only 1-3 results are actual Google results: http://tinypic.com/r/egz953/9

Does anyone know how to systemically get rid of this (Windows Defender is clueless, even after removing the obviously virus-added exclusions)?

Comment: If you go to a site with an HTTPS url (secure), do you see anything strange?  If not, I suspect an issue with your DNS settings (either on your computer, or on the router). Try another device on that network, do they see the same thing? If so its likely the router IMO.